# How to track backups

Tags: backup, reporting

We're in the midst of re-organizing our backup solution.  We currently have several different tools and scripts running on various machines in our network which run backups autonomously.  In the end, all the backups are to be consolidated onto a single NAS which will be rotated weekly.

What we'd like is something that tracks all of the final backups on the NAS and lets us know when one of them failed to occur.  Before rotating the NAS', the invididual would first check some form of report to find out if all the "backup targets" have been updated.

Are there any existing solutions?  We're a small enterprise so it can't be very expensive (ideally free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into centralizing your backup process with a [solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_backup_software) like [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) or the myriad of [non-free solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Backup_software). Other solutions might fit your environment better, but you haven't listed any details of what OS, the quantity of servers/data, or other specifics.

<sub>Links provided for ideas and do not represent an exhaustive list by any means.</sub>

Comment: I'm not looking for an all-in-one backup solution.  I want to keep it open to being a mixture of methods.   I'm just looking for a way to report on the final backup to the NAS.  We're mostly a Windows environment but I'll install linux on a box if I need to.

Comment: +1 for bacula. We backup several dozen servers with it, and it feeds its results into an EMC Networker (which then goes to tape). Works like a charm, with fully configurable notifications.

Comment: @Mr Grieves, without knowing what software you're currently using I have no way of knowing if it can be configured to report results or send notifications. I'm guessing that you're using a "solution" that's fairly duct-taped together and are simply hoping that everything works as intended. The reason most places ditch such methods are the very problems you are bringing up. Business mature, and their needs change; sounds like it's time for the Backup Methods to change with the business needs.

Comment: @Mr Grieves - if you're hard-set on using your homebrewed solution, one thing you could do pretty easily is to add logic to your scripts to email you the `stderr` output of each script. At least with that, you'll know pretty quickly when something goes awry.